# Help with CSS DIV borders needed, different view between IE and FireFox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, html, border

I am showing an image of differences in presenting borders for `div` elements between IE and FireFox. IE displays border in a correct way but FireFox not. As you might notice, the black border for `BorderDiv` seams to not respect the fact that its parent `div` has height of 78 pixels. Instead of it respects the height of most outer div. To complicate things, the right side of the border is drawn without respecting the most outer `div` also.

[image]

I am lost here. What do I need to do to achieve in FireFox the same result as in IE? Please note, that I want to have width and height for `BorderDiv` equal to 100%, I do not want to set it explicitly.

Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id = "MasterDiv" style = "float: left; width: 200px; height: 80px; background-color: Red">
    <div id = "RightDiv" style = "float: left; width: 100%; height: 78px; background-color: Blue;">
    <div id = "ContentColumn" style = "margin-left: 50px; height: 78px;">
    <div id = "BorderDiv" style = "border: solid 1px Black; height: 100%; width: 100%">right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "LeftDiv" style = "float: left; margin-left: -100%; width: 50px; height: 78px; background-color: Green;">left</div>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thanks.

Comment: FF: 3.6.12, IE: 8.0.7600

Comment: Never, ever trust IE to do ANYTHING right. Always, always use ANYTHING else. IE is NOT a modern browser.

Comment: I know, I just tried to be open-minded ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually the other way around: Firefox is correct, and IE is incorrect.

It is because of IE's bad implementation of the [box model](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

The div "BorderDiv" has a 100% height of its container div ("ContentColumn") which is 78px. Then, on top of that, the border, padding, and margin are added.

Why not just add the border to the "ContentColumn" div and get rid of the "BorderDiv" div altogether:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id = "MasterDiv" style = "float: left; width: 200px; height: 80px; background-color: Red">
    <div id = "RightDiv" style = "float: left; width: 100%; height: 78px; background-color: Blue;">
        <div id = "ContentColumn" style = "margin-left: 50px; height: 76px; border: solid 1px Black;">
            right
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "LeftDiv" style = "float: left; margin-left: -100%; width: 50px; height: 78px; background-color: Green;">
        left
    </div>
</div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

**Edit**
Modified the "ContentColumn" to have a height of 76px, to take into account the border size.

Also, you may want to look at avoiding [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) in IE so it will use the correct box model.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code. The look is consistant on both browsers. The right side of the order is presented correctly, but the bottom side is still 2 pixels down than it should be. How to fix that? I've added BorderDiv becasue I thought that I would be having some problems with seeting up a corect margins in the outer div but it works good without it.